# How to install filegdb driver with GDAL in linux?

Tags: gdal, file-geodatabase, ubuntu, linux

I have been working on GDAL with windows platform but now I require to shift to linux.
I have installed GDAL using

```
apt-get install gdal-bin libgdal-dev
pip3 install GDAL
```

Now i require support for GDB file hence , FileGDB driver is required.
can anyone help with a walk through to install FileGDB driver in linux ?
ogr2ogr --formats doesn't display fileGDB driver.

Comment: What version is 'gdalinfo --version' ? I always add the "unstable" repos to get something reasonably up to date, might be worth trying 'add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable'. The driver is called "OpenFileGDB". https://gdal.org/drv_openfilegdb.html

Comment: I have versions of Linux Mint that are running 2.18 and 3.2 versions of QGIS, and FGDB drivers have come out of the box!

Comment: have the same problem here. `GDAL 2.2.0` on ubuntu 18.04

Comment: gdalinfo --version gives : GDAL 2.2.3 released 2017/11/20 and I can't use openfilegdb as it has only read permission whereas I require write permission too.

Comment: Maybe related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/292506/how-do-i-install-esri-file-gdb-api-in-ubuntu-16-04-so-qgis-2-8-can-see-it